# Explain whether you can find matrix $A$ ($m\times n$) and two vectors $p$ and $q$ so that $Ax = p$ has no solution and $A^T y=q$ has only one solution

Tags: linear-algebra

> Explain whether you can find matrix $A$ ($m\times n$) and two vectors $p$ and $q$ so that $Ax = p$ has no solution and $A^T y=q$ has only one solution.

$Ax = p$ has no solution means the equation is inconsistent

$A^T y=q$ has one solution means it is consistent and $q$ is a linear combination of columns of $A^T$

$$\operatorname{Rank}(A^T) = m$$

How to use all of those information to decide whether it is possible to find matrix $A$?

Comment: Rank $A^T=m \implies m \le n$. Besides, what you have to prove is that such a matrix doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it like this? Rank (A) < m so rank (A) $\neq$ rank $A^T$ so A can not exist

Comment: No $rank(A)=rank(A^T)$ always.

Comment: But Ax = p has no solution so shouldn't rank (A) < m ?